# How to get a command block to say the name of a named mob

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a horse racing track and I want the game to say "[name of horse] has finished the race!" when a horse crosses the finish line. I can get it to say the name of every horse in the area, but not just the one that activates the block.

Comment: Could you give the command you use to get every horse in the area?

Answer (score 1):

If you're activating the command block with a pressure plate you could use the `@e` selector combined with `sort=nearest` and `limit=1` like this:

```
/tellraw @a ["",{"selector":"@e[sort=nearest,limit=1]"},
{"text":" has finished the race!"}]
```

If players are riding the horses you could also add `type=horse` in the selector:

```
/tellraw @a ["",{"selector":"@e[sort=nearest,limit=1,type=horse]"},
{"text":" has finished the race!"}]
```